# Can I wrap the legends or put the legends below the pie in react-native-chart-kit Pie Chart?

Tags: react-native, react-native-chart-kit

In my react-native-chart-kit pie chart, there will always be either absolutely no data (which I won't show the pie chart at all) or there are exactly two pieces of data.  By default, the legends are showing to the right of the pie. The actual text in the legend is coming from the name properties in data.  I have tried putting in a newline character (i.e. \n) but that didn't help.  So, is there a way to wrap the text in the legends to show in two lines?  Or can I change the position of the legend to right below the pie?

[image]